# convert raw data file to RData file

Tags: r, file, input, rdata

I am trying to make a RData file from a raw numeric space deliminated text file, i.e

```
11 33 55
22 33 45
25 78 00 
44 87 99 ....
```

I have another R script which needs to load this new RData file and perform linear regression with the data using mapreduce (rhipe). Thus when i save this RObject I need to read it back this way:

```
data <- strsplit(unlist(map.values)," ")

#so that I can run regression like:
y<- unlist(lapply(data,"[[",1))
x1<-unlist(lapply(data,"[[",2))
x2<-unlist(lapply(data,"[[",3))
lm(y~x1+x2)
```

I have tried many ways to save my data into the RData object, including table, list and as.character, but non of the succeed so that i can read it using my above method. How can I save my original file so that I can read it in the way I have above? Thank you.

(ps. i cannot use load / read.table functions since i am reading from a HDFS file inside the mapper)

Comment: Is https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/rhdfs any use?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,  you want your stored object to be a bunch of strings of the form "number - space - number" .  In that case,  use `sprintf`

```
foo <- sprintf('%d %d %d',my_data[1,])
```

as an example of creating the first row. Run a loop or `*apply` to build the entire array.  Save that character string array to an `RData` file.   This should at least be close to what you want.
Note: I suppose it's futile to suggest improving the far-end code which does the data sorting and regressions?

Comment: when i am reading back my .RData file using RHipe, i am getting something like:

filename   ï¿ t6ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½HNï¿½Dï¿½iï¿½TFl?ï¿½,ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zï¿½ï¿½MG6BUï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½fQ3ï¿½Ûï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ê´Jï¿½@ï¿½Óï¿½lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½n'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½dï¿½Aï¿½TTï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½[Nï¿½#`X1pA

what am i missing to decode this?